# Displaying items with certain custom field value in Netsuite

Tags: netsuite

Is there a way to display or filter (by editing a Template) all the products that match a certain Custom Field parameter (in example "custitem_outlet)"?

I have already added on the Netsuite backend these custom fields as checkboxes.

I would like to show the items on different Lists, in example one list will show the items with "custitem_outlet" checked and the other with "custitem_arrivals" checked.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what do you mean by editing a template?

Comment: Where exactly do you want to show the list. ?
And I am still not understanding what template refers to here ?

Comment: Hi, Rockstar and Swaraj. I mean editing the Template which is used by a Layout to show the Homepage in this case. 

In the same way you can call (in the Item Drilldown Page) for a _custom field_ value named as "custitem1" with <%=getCurrentAttribute("item","custitem1")%>, I suppossed that I can show an Item List of items in the Homepage which match that Custom Field. Hope I've clarified my question